# In Jekyll how can I capture year and month outside loop?

Tags: loops, jekyll, archive

Building an *archive.html* file in *_layouts* because Github will not allow the [archive plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives) I can build my file but I'm having issues trying to capture the month and year outside the loop. Typically this is done as:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign currentdate = post.date | date: "%B %Y" %}
  {% if currentdate != date %}
    <li id="y{{currentdate}}">{{ currentdate }}</li>
    {% assign date = currentdate %} 
  {% endif %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but if I want `currentdate` before the loop I've tried:

```
{% assign monthStamp = site.posts | post.date | date: "%B %Y" %}
```

gives me everything.

```
{% capture monthStamp %}{{ site.posts| post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
```

throws error:

> Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 1): Expected end_of_string
>   but found dot in "{{ site.posts| post.date | date: "%Y" }}" in
>   /_layouts/archive.html

In Jekyll can I get year and month for *archive.html* outside of the loop? In my Google kungfu search skills I'm unable to find any answers on this question or if it's been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like below:

```
{% assign latestPost = site.posts | first %}
{% assign monthStamp = latestPost.date | date: "%B %Y" %}
```